# Celery consumer (only) with an external producer

Tags: redis, celery

I'm using Celery 4.4.7 with Redis as my message broker.
I want to use celery as a consumer only, as the external producer is a java application.
The java application pushes messages to a channel on redis. But my celery application is not picking up the messages.

I have simulated the java producer in python using redis-py (redis_producer.py) to publish to a channel. The redis_consumer.py is able to pickup the messages from the producer.
But my celery_consumer.py seems to be blind to these messages.

Messages from redis_producer.py is picked up by the redis_consumer.py, but not from celery.
Messages from kombu_producer.py is picked up by the celery worker, but not from my redis_consumer.py

redis_producer.py

```
import json
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)
for i in range(10):
    body = {
        'id': i,
        'message': f'Hello {i}',
    }
    r.publish(channel='redis.test.topic', message=json.dumps(body))
```

---

redis_consumer.py

```
import json
import multiprocessing
import os
import signal

import redis

redis_conn = redis.Redis(charset='utf-8', decode_responses=True)


def sub(name: str):
    pubsub = redis_conn.pubsub()
    pubsub.subscribe('redis.test.topic')
    for message in pubsub.listen():
        print(message)
        if message.get('type') == 'message':
            data = message.get('data')
            print('%s: %s' % (name, data))


def on_terminate(signum, stack):
    wait_for_current_scp_operation()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.Process(target=sub, args=('consumer',)).start()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, on_terminate)
```

---

celery_consumer.py

```
import os
import ssl

from celery import Celery
from celery import shared_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from kombu import Exchange
from kombu import Queue

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

# Celery broker Url
broker_url = os.environ.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL', None)
if broker_url is None:
    broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

# store to use to store task results, default=None
result_backend = os.environ.get('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND', None)
if result_backend is None:
    result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

config = dict(
    broker_url=broker_url,
    result_backend=result_backend,

    # maximum number of connections that can be open in the connection pool
    broker_pool_limit=20,
    broker_transport_options={
        'visibility_timeout': 3600,
        'confirm_publish': True,
    },

    # Serializer method
    task_serializer='json',
    result_serializer='json',
    accept_content=['json'],

    # Below two settings just reserves one task at a time
    # Task acknowledgement mode, default=False
    task_acks_late=True,
    # How many message to prefetch, default=4, value=1 disable prefetch
    worker_prefetch_multiplier=1,

    # Dates and times in messages will be converted to use the UTC timezone
    timezone='UTC',
    enable_utc=True,

    # if true, store the task return values
    task_ignore_result=False,
    # if true, result messages will be persistent, messages won't be lost after a broker restart
    result_persistent=False,
    # Celery tasks expiry (in secs), default=1d, value=0/None never expire
    result_expires=900,

    # Message compression setting
    task_compression='gzip',

    # Task execution marker, default=False
    task_track_started=True,

    # rate limits on tasks (Disable all rate limits, even if tasks has explicit rate limits set)
    worker_disable_rate_limits=True,

    # is True, all tasks will be executed locally by blocking until the task returns
    task_always_eager=False,

    # Send events so the worker can be monitored by tools like celerymon
    worker_send_task_events=False,

    # Expiry time in seconds for when a monitor clients event queue will be deleted, default=never
    event_queue_expires=60,

    # Default queue, exchange, routing keys configuration
    # task_default_queue = 'default.queue',
    # task_default_exchange = 'default.exchange',
    # task_default_exchange_type='topic',
    # task_default_routing_key = 'default.route',
    # task_create_missing_queues = True
    task_queues=(
        # Default configuration
        Queue('redis.test.topic',
              Exchange('redis.test.topic'),
              routing_key='redis.test.topic'),
    ),
)


def create_celery_app() -> Celery:
    logger.info('Initializing Celery...')
    celery_app = Celery(name=__name__)
    celery_app.config_from_object(config)
    return celery_app


# create a celery app
app = create_celery_app()


@app.task(name='task_process_message', bind=True, max_retries=3)
def task_process_message(self, message):
    try:
        logger.info(f'{message}: Triggered task: task_process_message')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(
            f'Error executing task_process_message({message}')
        # We do not have to reset timestamp since the job always looks back by 1 hr
        self.retry(exc=e, countdown=utils.get_retry_delay(self.request.retries))


@shared_task(name='shared_task_process_message', bind=True, max_retries=3)
def shared_task_process_message(self, message):
    try:
        logger.info(f'{message}: Triggered task: shared_task_process_message')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(
            f'Error executing shared_task_process_message({message}')
        # We do not have to reset timestamp since the job always looks back by 1 hr
        self.retry(exc=e, countdown=utils.get_retry_delay(self.request.retries))
```

---

kombu_producer.py

```
from kombu import Producer, Consumer, Queue, Connection
import json

redis_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

conn = Connection(redis_url)

producer = Producer(conn.channel())

channel = 'redis.test.topic'

for i in range(10):
    body = {
        'task': 'task_process_message',
        'id': f'{i}',
        'kwargs': {'message': f'Hello {i}',
        }
    }

    producer.publish(body=body, routing_key='redis.test.topic')
```

---

The below picture shows activity on redis using a regular redis producer/consumer
[image: Activity on redis using a regular redis producer/consumer]

---

Below picture shows activity on redis while running kombu producer and celery consumer.
[image: Activity on redis with kombu producer and celery consumer]

Comment: did you solved this?